# error reading and merging a folder of data into one dataframe

Tags: r

If it helps, I'm running R 3.3.1 on a Macbook Pro OS El Captain...

I am trying to read in a folder of similar data files. I've checked the directory and the files are where they should be:

```
list.files('../data/')
 [1] "B101.txt"   "B101p2.txt" "B116.txt"   "B6.txt"     "B65.txt"    "B67.txt"    "B67p2.txt" 
 [8] "B70.txt"    "B71.txt"    "B71p2.txt"  "B95.txt"    "B95p2.txt"  "B96.txt"    "B96p2.txt"
[15] "B98.txt"    "B98p2.txt"  "B99.txt"    "B99p2.txt"
```

The following is my code and error:

```
a = ldply(
    .data = list.files(
        path = '../data/'
            )
    , .fun = function(x){
        to_return = read.table(
            file = x
            , skip = 20
            , sep = '\t'
            , fill = TRUE
                )
        return(to_return)
            }
    , .progress = 'text'
)

Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'B101.txt': No such file or directory
```

I do not know what the problem is as all searches for those errors suggest fixing the directory. I have also checked the data files and can read an individual file using:

```
read.table('../data/B101.txt', skip = 20, sep = '\t', fill=TRUE)
```

Could someone please help me to fix the problem of reading in the whole folder. I'm trying to sort out the script with a small number of files but will need it to run for a much larger number, so reading them in one by one isn't practical. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

By default, `list.files` returns ***only the filename itself***, not including the leading (relative or absolute) path (if any). When dealing with files potentially in another directory, you need to include `full.names = TRUE`:

```
a = ldply(
    .data = list.files(
        path = '../data/',
        full.names = TRUE
            )
    , .fun = function(x){
        to_return = read.table(
            file = x
            , skip = 20
            , sep = '\t'
            , fill = TRUE
                )
        return(to_return)
            }
    , .progress = 'text'
)
```